# What is the intuition behind a high Froude number causing instability in uniform flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, differential-equations, stability, intuition

Uniform flow in an inclined plane becomes unstable for high froude numbers.

I can follow the spectral analysis, but I am curious why I would *expect* high froude numbers to cause instability. What is the intuition?

Comment: Could you give more information on the problem you're considering? What is your definition of Froude number?